# Sorting a JSONField by adding an index value?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, key-value, django-jsonfield

I am using a `JSONField` to store a custom form with field labels/values. I am having an issue when rendering the form. Each time the form gets rendered, the order is changed since I am using a dictionary. I was thinking of adding an extra value to my `JSONField` just to store an integer, in which I can order by. I am wondering if this is a possible solution, or if there was any other "best" way to keep this form in order.

I have a simple model,

```
class House(models.Model):
    form = JSONField(default=dict)
```

Which in my view a json file is loaded into it with a json file as such.

```
{
    "outside": [
        {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "label": "Pool",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "label": "Shed",
                    "value": ""
                },
            ],
            "index": 0
        }
    ],

    "inside": [
        {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "label": "Bedrooms",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "label": "Baths",
                    "value": ""
                },
            ],
            "index": 1
        }
    ],
```

When the form is rendered in my view, I am using basic logic

```
house = House.objects.get(id=1)
form = house.form.items()
return render(request, template, context={'form': form}
```

The json loads fine the first time, with all fields with the label `outside` leading, and then fields with the label `inside` right after.

```
Outside
1.) Pool <input value="">
2.) Shed <input value="">

Inside
1.) Bedrooms <input value="">
2.) Baths <input value="">
```

Now running a hard page refresh, and printing out the `house.form.items()` the order is rearranged, and in doing so the template renders the form with `inside` fields leading, and `outside` fields following after. I definitely need to keep fields in order every time, so I added the index value, thinking it was a possibility to sort these items every time based off of the index value but really unsure of how to go about this?

Comment: Why not use lists instead of dictionaries if order matters?

Comment: I do need to use key/value pairs since this is actually being rendered as a form

the label(key) needs to have a value.
the value(key) needs to have a value.

I need them to have the association.